# Close Azure Security Center Alerts via Script/API

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-security

Is there a way to close a Azure Security Center Alert via a programmatic method such as PowerShell, Cli, C#, Python... or via API?

will really appreciate your assistance.

Searched online as well stack overflow, couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the security alert is generated according to the security policy.  So if you want to close one of the alert, you need to disable the corresponding policy.

You can disable it by rest api, please refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/tutorial-security-policy#configure-a-security-policy-using-the-rest-api

And below is the policy name for your reference:

[image]